# Ingresar Matrices en R

Tags: r

Quiero ingresar una cantidad `n` de matrices en R en una función, por ejemplo:

```
Matriz<- as.integer(readline(prompt="CUantas Matrices desea? "))

for(i in 1:Matriz){

  Fila = as.integer(readline(prompt="Ingrese el tamaño de la fila: "))

Columna = as.integer(readline(prompt="Ingrese el tamaño de la Columna: "))

 AA<- matrix(data = sample(-10:10, Fila*Columna, replace = FALSE), nrow = Fila, ncol = Columna)

}
```

ahi ingresa las matrices que uno desea, pero me las guarda en la variable `AA` y necesito que las guarde en diferentes variables, como puedo logar esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la primera es trabajar con un única lista e ir asignando cada matriz a un índice de esta lista.

Algo así:

```
lista <- list()
for(i in 1:5){
    lista[i]<-i # Acá asignamos la matriz
}

> lista[[1]]
[1] 1
```

La otra forma es crear variables dinámicamente usando [`assign()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html)

```
variables <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
for(i in 1:5){
    assign(variables[i], i) # Acá asignamos la matriz
}
> a
[1] 1
```

Comment: Perfecto Gracias